# Errors with structure in C (VS12)

Tags: function, struct, declaration, binary-search-tree

I'm making a Binary Search Tree, this is my code for the structure:

```
struct BST 
{
    float val;
    struct BST* left;
    struct BST* right;
};
```

Right after that, I make a few declarations of functions I'm going to use:

```
BST* BSTCreate(float);
void BSTFree(BST*);
int BSTAddElement(BST*, float);
```

When I try to run the whole thing, I'm getting really weird errors like  `missing '{' before '*'` (1st declaration line) or `missing ')' before '*'` (2nd dec. line). After that, in my `main()` function I have this line `BST tree;` and it says in an error that `'tree' : undeclared identifier`.
I have like 30 more wierd errors like those all across the program. Whats going on here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
struct BST 
{
    float val;
    struct BST* left;
    struct BST* right;
};
```

You would use:

```
struct BST* BSTCreate(float);
void BSTFree(struct BST*);
int BSTAddElement(struct BST*, float);
```

With this:

```
typedef struct BST 
{
    float val;
    struct BST* left;
    struct BST* right;
} BST;
```

Or this:

```
struct BST 
{
    float val;
    struct BST* left;
    struct BST* right;
};

typedef struct BST BST;
```

You can use:

```
BST* BSTCreate(float);
void BSTFree(BST*);
int BSTAddElement(BST*, float);
```

Comment: THANK YOU !
Can you please explain what does this line mean and why do I need it ?
typedef struct BST BST;

Comment: @user3105173 `typedef` tells C (or C++) that you are defining a type with a name you'd like to give it yourself. Since C/C++ doesn't have a type called `BST`, you can define your own with `typedef`. In this case, you are defining the type named `BST` as a `struct BST`. So you don't have to keep typing `struct BST` when you want something of that type. You can just say `BST`. You can also say things like, `typedef unsigned long UL;` and then use `UL x;` if you want `x` to be your own, special "unsigned long". See, for example, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_typedef.htm.